# Create New Row in database using Odata

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an OData Service that is pointing to a table in the database. I want to enter a new record in the table based on the details from user.

I am using the .create method, but the data doesn't seem to get entered in table.

```
oView=this.getView();
var df = {};
var name = oView.byId("__input3").getValue();  
var goal = oView.byId("__area0").getValue();

df.NAME = name;
df.GOAL = goal;
df.TYPE = "type";
df.THEME = "Theme";

var oModel1= new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/GDH_OData/services/df.xsodata/");
oModel1.create('/Df', df, null, function() {
    alert("SUCCESS");
}, function() {
    alert("FAIL");
});
```

Please help where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

you're not giving a lot of info, here...

- what is the result of your create call ? SUCCESS or FAIL ? if the later, what is the error message returned ? the following error function can help you on this

  function(error) {
     var message = $(error.response.body).find('message').first().text();
     console.log(message);
     alert(message);
  }
- Is the creation code in the backend called (if you put an external breakpoint in your service, do you get the debugger ?) if so, what is the result of debugging step-by-step ?

***edit***
if there is a "forbidden" response, then you should check the result of transaction su53 for the user. You'll probably have a failed  autorization. Then it's just adding the service to your role autorisation.

PS : its better to add your answer to my questions(s) in your question, under a "edit" or "more information" than to put it as another answer. Thus there is only one place to check for the whole problem.

regards

Answer (score -1):

The result is Fail and the error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"